# Correct NodeJS server for Vue.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm using `Vue.js` and the `vue-router` and would like to server the static files via `Node.JS`.
So I've create `server.js` with the following code:

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');

var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port);

console.log('server started '+ port);
```

It seems to work, but only when I click around.
If I visit ex. `my-url.com/some-path/another-path` it fails.

Am I missing something?

Ex. I'm getting:

`Cannot GET /cars` with I type www.my-domain.com/cars into the address bar in the browser, but visiting www.my-domain.com and clicking on cars does work.

Comment: You are having the same issue that [Cant make router work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51048098/691711) is facing.  Please read [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode).

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your server to redirect users to the appropriate server location.  Please read the [Vue Router - HTML5 History Mode docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).

> When using history mode, the URL will look "normal," e.g.
>   `http://oursite.com/user/id`. Beautiful!
>
> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client
>   side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a
>   404 error if they access `http://oursite.com/user/id` directly in
>   their browser. Now that's ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple
>   catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any
>   static assets, it should serve the same `index.html` page that your
>   app lives in. Beautiful, again!

The main thing that you need to do is have all routes lead to the root route.  Alternatively, since you are using Express, you can leverage the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) which the [Vue Router docs recommend](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).